# How to listen to an event coming from a component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to llisten to an event that I can see in Chrome DevTools Vue, but which I do not know how to address.

For a Root event I use

```
this.$root.$on("note_id", (note_id) => (this.note_id = note_id));
```

How should I address an event that comes from a specific component? In the example below, I would like to act upon the `hide` event:

[image]

To take the `$root` example below, I would like to use

```
this.<here I do not know what to use>.$on("hide", () => this.someVariable = true);
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your template? As this is being emitted by QDialog. Depending on your template you may need to use @hide in the <QDialog> component

Comment: @SuitBoyApps: I will try to extract that - what I was actually hoping that since Chrome can see the event emitted by anything (`QDialog` in my case, a [Quasar](https://quasar.dev) component), I could myself also listen to events emitted by "that component", no matter how deep it is.

Comment: I see what you are after. What about `this.$on`? It will catch all events no matter what

Comment: I just tried `this.$on("hide", () => this.someVariable = true);` but it was not acted upon. I will continue this way if all events are supposed to be caught, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried assigning a component reference like <qdialog ref="myDialog"> and accessing it via this.$refs.myDialog.$on(...)?

Comment: @mynd: Yes I did, and did not manage to catch the event either.

Comment: @mynd: ah? by manipulating where the ref is set I finally managed that way, thanks (I put the ref on the component when it is called as part of the attributes, not "inside" it)

Comment: @mynd: could you turn that into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @WoJ Happy to do that. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to the component (`<your-component ref="yourComponent" />`) and then access its events via

```
this.$refs.yourComponent.$on(...)?
```